# wpf source and target binding in two different path

Tags: wpf, data-binding

How can I bind a Text property for my `TextBox` that read from a source but it will store its value to a different target?
Let's say
I have a textbox which is bond to a path in a `CollectionViewSource`

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProgramView}, Path='FK_LevelList_ProgramList'}" x:Key="LevelLookupView" />
   </Window.Resources>

   <TextBox Name="FeePerTermTextbox" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LevelLookupView}, Path='FeePerTerm', Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=c2}"/>   
</Window>
```

When perform save, the value of the `TextBox` will store to another model that is different from the `CollectionViewSource`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I consider this flawed. What happens if the source gets updated? Should the textbox be overwritten? 
The reason for this design is imho, that the UI should reflect the "traits" of the element set as DataContext, therefore i expect it to contain the value i give in the model or in the ui. Now there is of course nothing stopping you from not writing the value in your viewmodel to your model, when receiving the set value from the textbox.

```
public class Redirecter
{
    public string FileName
    {
        get{return mModel.FileName;}
        set{mProxy.FileName = value;}
    }
}
```

But this of course won't work well together with INotifyPropertyChanged. I would use a different approach. Use a model that reflects your ui more. If you open the view fill in this ui model with your settings from model A. If you now save this, save each property into Model B.